# How do I compile ImageMagick with support for a patched version of Autotrace?

Tags: gcc

**yum is not an option here**

I have downloaded, patched, configured, compiled, and installed autotrace. Files on the system with the autotrace name are:

```
/usr/local/include/autotrace/autotrace.h
/usr/local/man/man1/autotrace.1
/usr/local/bin/autotrace
/usr/local/bin/autotrace-config
/usr/local/share/aclocal/autotrace.m4
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/autotrace.pc
```

I am trying to compile ImageMagick with the command:

```
./configure --with-autotrace LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/include/autotrace CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/autotrace
```

but I still get the following in the output:

```
...
Autotrace         --with-autotrace=yes        no
...
```

What am I missing? How do I tell configure what it is missing, in order for autotrace to be found and linked?

Comment: Have you tried `configure --with-autotrace=yes` as the output you posted suggests?

Comment: I just gave it a shot, and came up with the same output

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (in Ubuntu) and got it working by installing `autotrace` from source and configuring `ImageMagick` only with the `--with-autotrace` flag (without `LDFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`)

```
# build and install autotrace from source
cd /tmp
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/autotrace/files/AutoTrace/0.31.1/autotrace-0.31.1.tar.gz
tar xvzf autotrace-0.31.1.tar.gz
cd /tmp/autotrace-0.31.1
./configure
make
sudo make install

# build and install ImageMagick
cd /tmp
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd /tmp/ImageMagick-7.0.3-5
./configure --with-autotrace
make
sudo make install
```